# Manually configure WCF to use HTTP on Vista home premium

Tags: wcf, windows-vista, netsh

I'm trying to develop and deploy a WCF service using VS2008 and Vista home premium. I don't have IIS running and understand I don't need to if I manually configure the WCF app ... using netsh.exe I believe.

Can anyone give me clear guidance on how to go from the development project in VS2008 to a useable service?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WCF service needs a host to run. As IIS is out of the question you have a couple of possibilities left:

1. Write a [Windows NT service and host it there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)
2. Write a [managed application which will host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) your service (less robust)

As far as `netsh.exe` is concerned I don't see much relevance with WCF.